# Android widget multiple sizes do you determine what size they picked in the configure activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I have built a android widget that allows for multiple sizes 2x2 and 4x2.  So when someone is on the widget picker screen they see both sizes.  They click on one of the sizes and it goes to my configuration activity.  How do I know what size they picked on the widget picker screen.  I need to know which one was chosen on the configuration activity.  I am having trouble of how to move forward and what direction to look into.  Below is my manifest file just in case you think it might clarify what I am doing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.corradodev.customizable_countdown_widget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <!-- Configure Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".configure">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Broadcast Receivers that will process AppWidget updates -->
        <receiver android:name=".customizable_countdown_widget_large" android:label="@string/app_name_large">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
                       android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_large" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".customizable_countdown_widget_small" android:label="@string/app_name_small">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
                       android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_small" />
        </receiver>
         <!-- Service for updating -->
        <service android:name=".widget_service" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help.

**Solution:**
In the oncreate of the configure activity

```
   Bundle mExtras = mIntent.getExtras();
if (mExtras != null) {
    mAppWidgetId = mExtras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}
//Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(mAppWidgetId));

// If they gave us an intent without the widget id, close
if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
    finish();
}
AppWidgetProviderInfo providerInfo = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).getAppWidgetInfo(mAppWidgetId);
String minWidth=String.valueOf(providerInfo.minWidth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use `AppWidgetProviderInfo AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(int appWidgetId)` and check `minSize', etc. once you have the wdiget ID. You can get it from the config activity like this:

```
int id = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not realize you can get the data from the widget provider xml.  I added the full code to my question.  Thanks again.

Comment: After getting the AppWidgetProviderInfo you could also use the provider field instead of checking for minSize.